# mark as read a facebook notification from client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

I'm writing a Firefox addon to hide the facebook "like notifications".
The hidding part was easy, just needed to apply .hide() using jQuery to every element that matches.

But the problem is that if you just hide those notifications, you still got them counted in the notification bar counter (red little number above the globe icon), despite the fact that if you click in the notification bar, you don't see them.

So I figured out that the way to make these "counters" don't count the like notifications, is to "view" the notifications (but without actually seeing them).
I want to replicate exactly what happens when you normally click a notification, but I don't want to actually click the notification by hand.

Using Firefox console, I saw that when a notification is clicked, a GET Request is sent whit the following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/notifications/mark_read.php?__a=1&__dyn=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&__req=3f&__rev=11111111&__user=1111111111111&alert_ids%5B0%5D=2222222222&asyncSignal=3333&fb_dtsg=YYYYYYYYYYY&seen=true&ttstamp=4444444444444444444444444
```

(I replaced the data with random values)

My question is if there is a way to replicate/simulate this request in javascript?
And if replicating the GET Request is impossible, is there ANY other way to do this?

I know if use Facebook's Graph API, I can use this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/ but I can't use it because it needs a facebook APP KEY and what I'm doing isn't a Facebook App.

Comment: have you tried progmatically executing a click even on the globe? eg: `$('#element').click()`

Comment: Yes, and doesn't happen anything. I tried .trigger('click'); and also mousedown, mouseup. I think Facebook it's protected server side to poo prevent clickjacking: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking .